# setTimeout callbacks have different execution orders in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: javascript, settimeout, event-loop

When I run this code in Firefox and Chrome, the results are different:

```
function run() {
  setTimeout(() => console.log("1"), 0);
  setTimeout(() => console.log("2"), 100);

  let start = Date.now();
  while (Date.now() - start < 200) {
    // do nothing
  }
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("3");
  }, 0);

  start = Date.now();
  while (Date.now() - start < 200) {
    // do nothing
  }
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("4");
  }, 0);
}

run();
```

In Chrome (and Node.js), this is printed:

```
1
3
2
4
```

In Firefox, this is printed:

```
1
2
3
4
```

But if I remove the line 2 (`setTimeout(() => console.log("1"), 0);`), then the same thing is printed on every platform:

```
2
3
4
```

How to explain these different results?

Thanks!

Comment: In both chrome and firefox I get the same result: 1, 2, 3, 4

Comment: I updated Chrome and you're right, the results are the same as in Firefox now... but it's different in Node (v16). I guess ShadowRanger is right, it doesn't matter because it's undocumented. Still, it's interesting to know that you can't be sure of the order of execution of these setTimeout callbacks and it can change between different versions of the browser

Answer (score 3):

##### The explanation: It doesn't matter.

The details of when deferred "messages" are added to the event loop message queue are implementation details, not documented guarantees. By the time your function yields control back to the event loop, *all* of your `setTimeout` call are eligible to execute (three of them were scheduled to run immediately, one of them was scheduled to run in 100 ms) and you've guaranteed it's been at least 400 ms since you scheduled it.

The difference between the two could be as simple as whether they choose to look for deferred tasks that have become ready (to move from the deferred queue to the main "ready to go" message queue) immediately before or immediately after new items are inserted in the main message queue. Chrome chooses to move immediately *after* `3` is scheduled (so `3` goes in, then the deferred `2`), Firefox immediately *before* (moving in `2` before it puts `3` in).

**Both of them could change in the next release without violating any documented guarantees. Don't rely on it, don't expect it to be stable.** [While immediately scheduled tasks are guaranteed to execute in FIFO order](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop#queue), [there are no guarantees on when deferred tasks get moved onto the "ready-to-go" message queue](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop#adding_messages). The spec seems to requires that `1`, `3` and `4` execute in that order (since they were all immediately ready, not deferred), with only the ordering of `2` being flexible, but even that isn't a true guarantee; it can get weird with [the various ways in which an "immediate" `setTimeout` task may not actually be scheduled immediately](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout#reasons_for_delays_longer_than_specified).

You may be interested in the MDN docs on [why `setTimeout` can take longer than expected](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout#reasons_for_delays_longer_than_specified); it explains by side-effect a lot of how the event loop works, even as it carefully provides no guarantees on the details you're exploring.

Comment: No this is completely wrong. The specs ask that any two task queued on the same task source are executed in queuing order. Here the issue is about what clock time the timer represents.

Comment: @Kaiido: Hmm... You're right, at least to some extent. [The MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop#queue) note that "At some point during the event loop, the runtime starts handling the messages on the queue, starting with the oldest one." That said, [they also say, regarding `setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop#adding_messages) "The time value represents the (minimum) delay after which the message will be pushed into the queue." So the delayed `setTimeout` isn't *in* the queue initially, and the rules for when...

Comment: ...it moves are not well-specified AFAICT.

Comment: @Kaiido: I've updated the answer. I think, from the spec, that it *kinda* guarantees that it must go `1`, `3`, `4`, with `2`'s order within that ordering being flexible; it must be after `1`, that's all (because no guarantees are given regarding when a deferred task moves to the message queue for processing). But the security/performance/privacy quirks that `setTimeout` allows for (which can make `delay == 0` tasks turn into `delay > 0` tasks) might break even that guarantee (that's not the event loop's fault though, it's a quirk specific to `setTimeout`).

Answer (score 1):

I can't give you an full detailed explanation, but the second paramter of `setTimeoput` and `setInterval` doesn't mean, it will exactly execute it at that time. They will put it in a queue, so the background can execute it.

The browser has a lifecycle when to execute specific steps to update the data and the styles.
I can only send you this youtube link, that helped me to learn more about it:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MCi6AZMkxcU